# django template - and operator does not work in if block

Tags: django, templates, if-statement, operator-keyword

In views.py:

```
all_pages = 5
```

In html file:

```
{% if all_pages > 2 and page = 1 %}
    <a href='...'>next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Why `and` operator does not work here?

With using `{% if all_pages > 2 %}` the link appears but when I use `and` operator, nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I found the answer myself.

This:

```
{% if all_pages > 2 and page = 1 %}
    <a href='...'>next</a>
{% endif %}
```

should be changed like this to work :|

```
{% if all_pages > 2 and page == '1' %}
    <a href='...'>next</a>
{% endif %}
```

The only changing was here `page == '1'` after the `and` operator.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

`and` works. you have a typo: you need `==` instead of single `=`

```
{% if all_pages > 2 and page == 1 %}
    <a href='...'>next</a>
{% endif %}
```

you could also write:

```
{% if all_pages > 2 and not paginated_items.has_previous %}
    <a href='...'>next</a>
{% endif %}
```

`paginated_items` is your paginated queryset

Comment: I even have tried `==` before asking my question but still nothing changed.

Comment: @niloofar then you have something else which is buggy